# How to configure Spring WebClient to use Gson instead of Jackson?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, gson

I`m building a Java Client with Spring (no Spring Boot) and have to use Gson.

How do I tell Spring to use Gson instead of Jackson?

For clarification I use the reactive WebClient:

```
WebClient wc = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost").build();
Pojo myPojo = wc.get.uri("/pojo").retrieve().bodyToMono(Pojo.class).block();
```

And the Pojo be something like this:

```
public class Pojo {

    @SerializedName("Id")
    private long id;

    @SerializedName("Value")
    private String value;

    private Pojo() {

    }
}
```

And the Json from the Server be like this:

```
{"Id":1,"Value":"some Value"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Spring-Boot to use Gson instead of Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786366/force-spring-boot-to-use-gson-instead-of-jackson)

Comment: Not realy, because my Client isn`t a SpringBootApplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "Java Client"? Do you mean an HTTP client based on, e.g, `RestTemplate`? Then it's simple:

```java
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
    Collections.singletonList(new GsonHttpMessageConverter())
);
```

Comment: Yeah but I use the new WebClient.

Comment: @Jonny, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855905/750510) answer your question?

Comment: Im not sure if this is a dirty hack or the right way, but it worked for now. Thanks